# Learning Fourier Integral

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, self-learning

I am learning Fourier Integral for real numbers. I downloaded a presentation of some university. I am summing up what I know and hopefully someone will correct me where I am wrong.

Fourier integral can be calculated only for functions that are **decaying** (what ever that means) and **non-periodic**

The formula for Fourier Integral :
$$
f(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty}(A(\lambda)Cos(\lambda x)+B(\lambda)Sin(\lambda x)))\ d\lambda
$$ where $\lambda$ is real numbers greater than or equal to zero.

Also my question is:
Fourier Series allows you to express a piece-wise continuous, periodic function as a sum of infinite terms. What does Fourier integral do ?

Comment: You can think of the Fourier transform as being a generalization of the coefficients you see in Fourier series.

Answer (score 1):

> only for functions that are decaying (what ever that means) and non-periodic

Basically, yes. "Decaying" can be interpreted as "integrable" or "square integrable" (in terms of function spaces, $L^1$ or $L^2$). "Non-periodic" is redundant, since a function integrable in any sense cannot be periodic unless it's identically zero.

> What does Fourier integral do ?

It helps us solve differential equations, by converting differentiation to multiplication (similarly to its close relative Laplace transform). It helps the folks over at [Digital Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com) analyse sound, images, and other kinds of signals. Other ways to use the Fourier transform are listed at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Applications).